# Can't display modal from link in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a script that I need to be able do trigger a modal from a link from my jQuery. When a user clicks on the `thumbnail` class, a full screen modal should appear with more info.

I have the following, but stuck on how to organize the code so that the page works:

```
$(function(){
$.getJSON('url', function(data) {
    for(var key in data.results) {
      var poster = data.results[key].poster_path,
          title = data.results[key].title,
          description = data.results[key].overview;
          if(data.results.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                  $('<img class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 thumbnail">').attr({
                    src:'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342' + poster
                  }).appendTo($('<a  title=' + title + ' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal-fullscreen'/>').attr({
                    href:'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342' + poster
                  }).appendTo($('.container')));
          }
          $('body').append("<div class="modal modal-fullscreen fade" id="modal-fullscreen" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">\
              <div class="modal-dialog">\
                <div class="modal-content">\
                  <div class="modal-header">\
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>\
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>\
                  </div>\
                  <div class="modal-body">\
                    <p>This is the title of the movie</p>\
                  </div>\
                  <div class="modal-footer">\
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>\
                  </div>\
                </div>\
              </div>\
            </div>");
      }
});
});
```

With the modal in its current place, the page doesn't work at all. I will also need to be able to grab data from the data feed as well, to populate the modal window.

This is a sample object that the modal needs to grab information from:

```
{
poster_path: "/e1mjopzAS2KNsvpbpahQ1a6SkSn.jpg",
overview: "details about movie",
release_date: "2016-08-03",
id: 297761,
original_title: "Title of movie",
original_language: "en",
title: "Title of movie",
popularity: 44.788935,
vote_count: 1552,
}
```

Comment: i would suggest to not append a modal for every data found in the request, write it on HTML instead and edit the contents just right before you toggle the modal

Comment: Are you saying to move the modal outside of the for loop (which was an accident) and make it `$('body').html(" ");`? Or put the modal in the HTML itself? I tried in the HTML, but it wasn't triggering.

Comment: i mean to write the Modal skeleton in HTML itself, you can then add the contents using identifiers like `class` or `id`, right after editing the modal, you can trigger it from an HTML button or by calling it from JavaScript, check on http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals for details

Comment: I've reorganized my code, but I need to be able to display dynamic values in the modal, based on whatever link I clicked from the returned JSON.

Comment: You can show your information from the request, you just have to edit the contents of the modal before you show it.. for instance, you edit the modal title by doing `$(".modal-title").innerHTML("my title")`, then you edit the rest of the modal structure by doing the same.. it is recommended to add common static elements to the modal which will never change, and then fill the elements with your dynamic data, then you show your modal by executing `$("#myModal").modal("toggle");`

Comment: One of the first problems, is that I'm having an issue triggering the modal from my current state. Could you provide an example from the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/mattography/Lxo9mfby/3/

Comment: i have added an example on your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lxo9mfby/5/ , i don't know if you had in mind that you select the elements as if it was css selector, you must also know that jquery cannot select dynamic elements directly because they are not found by jQuery when the document loads

Comment: Ah, there's a misunderstanding here. There shouldn't be a generated modal for each of the objects returned. Rather, there should be a static modal html that is passed details of one of the returned results that the user clicks on, based on its `id`. When the user clicks the poster image, a modal should pop up display additional details on that movie from the object.